# Flickering and smoothing issue in Viewport and Render

Tags: rendering, animation

i have a problem in Blender 4.0, where when i animate a camera to move, everything in the Render (EEVEE) gets smoother and also shadows and meshes start to flicker (and also lights appear out of the blue).

Here are two Videos, one screen capture and one render:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7CxqpPmN1JA

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2AHJMEN42E

I dont know, what changed in my system, that this occurs.
I even have a Render, where that didnt happen:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RdVq0UAyyes

changing Clip start and End didnt help, unchecking "Soft Shadows" helped just a little bit, but nothing seems to work definately.

I didnt try other Blender Versions yet, but i will try that now and report if that helped or not.
In the meantime, any help is welcome and thanks in advance.

EDIT: Okay, previous Versions dont work either.
Here the Blend Files:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1stx4L2JrLUneHQLBX1xPC_lbR0phGpj6?usp=drive_link

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: usually it hard to help if you don't provide a file, even better a minimal setup where this occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this can be closed ... the flickering was a "Clip Start" Issue ... Why in this scene, it did NOW help, when in other situations and projects AND THIS ONE, it didnt help before, i dont know, the 3d Vodoo Gods seemed now to help in this instance.

The Viewport Smoothing or Distorting was fixed with unchecking "Viewport denoising", calculating it froze the texture in place and therefore it was "smoothing it" but actually it was frozen ... why it rendered with it, and now doesnt, same 3d Vodoo Gods at play i think.

So this thread can be closed.